# Enterprise Library 5 Logging to database contention

Tags: database, logging, enterprise-library

I am looking to capture WCF request/response information through using the Enterprise Library logging block and writing the captured information to a database table. My one concern is that this could become a source of contention with many different WCF services attempting to log to this one table.

Does Enterprise Library Logging handle the issue with contentions in this case or do I need to actually use something like MSMQ and use MSMQ to write logs to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download the source for enterprise library you can look through all of the classes you are using.

That said, the logger class will only write one message at a time using a lock.  If you are writing tons of messages and performance is a concern then you might want to read up on the AutoFlush setting and cache up your messages and perhaps write on a different thread or something.